# React-Bootstrap: separate two buttons in navbar

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I have a react-bootstrap Navbar defined as follows, but I can't seem to find a way to put some space between the Login and Register buttons: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTFhm.png) the output I get instead.

```js
<Navbar id="navigation-bar" collapseOnSelect sticky="top" expand="lg" bg="light" variant="light">
          <Navbar.Brand href="/">Sort-CVA</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="/upload-form">Upload Results</Nav.Link>
              {/*<Nav.Link href="/login">Login</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="/register">Register</Nav.Link>*/}
              <Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            <Form inline >
              <Button variant="primary" href="/login">Login</Button>
              <Button variant="outline-primary" href="/register">Register</Button>
            </Form>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using bootstrap you can take advantage of the bootstrap utility classes, in your first button you can do:

```
<Button variant="primary" href="/login" className="mr-2">Login</Button>
```

That `mr-2` class would add some margin right to your button, which is exactly what you need in order to create some space between them.